# Do I need to set refit=FALSE when testing for random effects in lmer() models with anova()?

Tags: r, anova, lmer

I am currently testing whether I should include certain random effects in my lmer model or not. I use the anova function for that. My procedure so far is to fit the model with a function call to `lmer()` with `REML=TRUE` (the default option). Then I call `anova()` on the two models where one of them does include the random effect to be tested for and the other one doees not. However, it is well known that the `anova()` function refits the model with ML but in the new version of `anova()` you can prevent `anova()` from doing so by setting the option `refit=FALSE`. In order to test for random effects should I set `refit=FALSE` in my call to `anova() or not?` (If I do set `refit=FALSE` the p-values tend to be lower. Are the p-values anti-conservative when I set `refit=FALSE`?)

**Method 1:**

```
    mod0_reml <- lmer(x ~ y + z + (1 | w), data=dat)
    mod1_reml <- lmer(x ~ y + z + (y | w), data=dat)
    anova(mod0_reml, mod1_reml)
```

This will result in `anova()` refitting the models with `ML` instead of `REML`. (Newer versions of the `anova()` function will also output an info about this.)

**Method 2:**

```
    mod0_reml <- lmer(x ~ y + z + (1 | w), data=dat)
    mod1_reml <- lmer(x ~ y + z + (y | w), data=dat)
    anova(mod0_reml, mod1_reml, refit=FALSE)
```

This will result in `anova()` performing its calculations on the original models, i.e. with `REML=TRUE`.

Which of the two methods is correct in order to test whether I should include a random effect or not?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general I would say that it would be appropriate to use `refit=FALSE` in this case, but let's go ahead and try a simulation experiment.

First fit a model without a random slope to the `sleepstudy` data set, then simulate data from this model:

```
library(lme4)
mod0 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject), data=sleepstudy)
## also fit the full model for later use
mod1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), data=sleepstudy)
set.seed(101)
simdat <- simulate(mod0,1000)
```

Now refit the null data with the full and the reduced model, and save the distribution of p-values generated by `anova()` with and without `refit=FALSE`. This is essentially a parametric bootstrap test of the null hypothesis; we want to see if it has the appropriate characteristics (i.e., uniform distribution of p-values).

```
sumfun <- function(x) {
    m0 <- refit(mod0,x)
    m1 <- refit(mod1,x)
    a_refit <- suppressMessages(anova(m0,m1)["m1","Pr(>Chisq)"])
    a_no_refit <- anova(m0,m1,refit=FALSE)["m1","Pr(>Chisq)"]
    c(refit=a_refit,no_refit=a_no_refit)
}
```

I like `plyr::laply` for its convenience, although you could just as easily use a `for` loop or one of the other `*apply` approaches.

```
library(plyr)
pdist <- laply(simdat,sumfun,.progress="text")

library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
library(reshape2)
ggplot(melt(pdist),aes(x=value,fill=Var2))+
     geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),
        alpha=0.5,position="identity",binwidth=0.02)+
     geom_hline(yintercept=1,lty=2)
ggsave("nullhist.png",height=4,width=5)
```

[image: histogram of null distributions]

Type I error rate for alpha=0.05:

```
colMeans(pdist<0.05)
##   refit no_refit 
##   0.021    0.026
```

You can see that in this case the two procedures give practically the same answer and *both* procedures are strongly conservative, for well-known reasons having to do with the fact that the null value of the hypothesis test is on the boundary of its feasible space.  For the specific case of testing a single simple random effect, halving the p-value gives an appropriate answer (see Pinheiro and Bates 2000 and others); this actually appears to give reasonable answers here, although it is not really justified because here we are dropping *two* random-effects parameters (the random effect of slope and the correlation between the slope and intercept random effects):

```
colMeans(pdist/2<0.05)
##   refit no_refit 
##   0.051    0.055
```

Other points:

- You might be able to do a similar exercise with the `PBmodcomp` function from the `pbkrtest` package.
- The `RLRsim` package is designed precisely for fast randomization (parameteric bootstrap) tests of null hypotheses about random effects terms, but doesn't appear to work in this slightly more complex situation
- see the relevant [GLMM faq section](http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq#random-sig)  for similar information, including arguments for why you might not want to test the significance of random effects at all ...
- for extra credit you could redo the parametric bootstrap runs using the deviance (-2 log likelihood) differences rather than the p-values as output and check whether the results conformed to a mixture between a `chi^2_0` (point mass at 0) and a `chi^2_n` distribution (where `n` is *probably* 2, but I wouldn't be sure for this geometry)

Comment: I have one follow up question but first: (Although it is suggested not to do it in the comments I will do it anyway.) Thank you, that was a really helpful answer! I was worried that I might be calculating effects into significance so parametric bootstrapping was exactly what I planned to do. I also managed to read quite a deal about fitting lmer() models but there seem to be so many ways of doing it that I was still unsure.

Here’s the follow up question: When I want to test for the significance of fixed effects via parametric bootstrapping should I fit the lmer() model with ML or REML?

Comment: If you're ever comparing models with different fixed effects you should **always** use ML and **never** use REML.  Otherwise the results are likely to be garbage.